# Avoid unique constraint exception while update or create entry to pivot table using Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, error-handling, eloquent

I have two table *user*, *group* and an intermediate pivot table *user_group*. The user_group table had four property *user_id, group_id, count and recorded_at*. I have set a unique constraint for *user_id, group_id, recorded_at* combination for *user_group*. I am trying to insert new data to *user_group* table if *user_id, group_id, recorded_at* combination does not exists in the pivot table.

```
$user->groups()->save($group[0], ['count' => $request->count, 'recorded_at' => now()]); 
\\ This line works for inserting new data when the user_group table has no entry for user_id, group_id, recorded_at combination
```

When there is an entry for unique combination, I am getting QueryException for unique constraint failure for the previous code block.

```
lluminate\Database\QueryException #23000
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7-52-2020-09-20' for key 'group_user_group_id_user_id_recorded_at_unique' (SQL: insert into `group_user` (`count`, `group_id`, `recorded_at`, `user_id`) values (0, 7, 2020-09-20 08:54:22, 52))
```

If the entry exists, I need to update the *count* column. To achieve this, I have tried to following code block.

```
try{
     $user->groups()->save($group[0], ['count' => $request->count, 'recorded_at' => now()]);
}catch(QueryExceptoin $ex){
     $user->groups()->updateExistingPivot($group[0], ['count' => $request->count, 'recorded_at' => now()]);
}
```

This block tries to catch if there is entry for unique combination, then tries to update the required *count* column. However, this code is not able to catch the query exception so my update is failing. I have two question. 1) Is there any better way to do for what I am trying to achieve? 2) Why try catch can not catch the query exception and how can I make it catch?

I am using Laravel 8, with PHP 7.4.5.

I have checked the suggested similar questions carefully, I believe they do not reflect my situation exactly.

Comment: Can you show which  exception / error message is thrown?

Comment: I have added the message in my question.

Comment: Which exception have imported and what line does exactly fail?

Comment: I have clarified in the text above the error message.

Comment: `QueryExceptoin` is a typo in the question or in your code?

Comment: It is a type in the question not in the code.